# Strings was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: vb.net

When I try to insert null values for the masktextbox which are masked with date format, it shows the error , can anyone help to solve it?

```
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GradDateDeg", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Date.Parse(mskGradDate1.Text)
```

mskGradDate1 is the masktextbox & my database table column for the textbox is date datatype but I allow null value for that column, can the null value be converted as well?

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: The second parameter in `.AddWithValue` is and object which is meant to contain the value of the parameter. You seem to be mixing this up with the `.Add` method where the second parameter is the `SqlDbType` and you include the value just as you have shown. The `.Add` method is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the Null value separately. Try this:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(mskGradDate1.Text) Then cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GradDateDeg", DBNull.Value) Else cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GradDateDeg", Date.Parse(mskGradDate1.Text))
```